# how to show an error from callable cloud function?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

from the documentation in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable)

I can throw error using syntax like this

```
throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called ' +
      'while authenticated.');
```

and in Android device

```
private fun addMessage(text: String): Task<String> {
    // Create the arguments to the callable function.
    val data = hashMapOf(
        "text" to text,
        "push" to true
    )

    return functions
            .getHttpsCallable("addMessage")
            .call(data)
            .continueWith { task ->
                // This continuation runs on either success or failure, but if the task
                // has failed then result will throw an Exception which will be
                // propagated down.
                val result = task.result?.data as String
                result
            }
}

addMessage(inputMessage)
        .addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                val e = task.exception
                if (e is FirebaseFunctionsException) {
                    val code = e.code
                    val details = e.details
                }

                // ...
            }

            // ...
        })
```

how do I get error message that thrown from cloud function ? I want to show the error message from cloud function using toast

> The function must be called ' + 'while authenticated.

the syntax in Android is weird. in the detail ? but the detail is `any`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message `"The function must be called while authenticated."` will be set as the native Exception's message.

So to use it, you would get the value of `e.message`.

Regarding `e.details`, this is an optional object that contains the data passed as the third argument to `functions.https.HttpsError`.

So for the exception below, `e.details` will contain the missing parameter name:

```
throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'Missing required parameter', 'count');
```